# Compare Lists in Unity3D/C#

Tags: unity, c#

Hi guys I am working on a combo feature and I want to compare two C# lists, something like this

```
bool found = false;

List<int> combo = new List<int>();
combo.add(1);
combo.add(1);
combo.add(1);

List<int> playerCombo = new List<int>();
playerCombo.add(1);
playerCombo.add(1);
playerCombo.add(1);

if(combo == playerCombo){
  found = true
}
```

The thing is that == seems that does not work, always throws false, any ideas?

Update: already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669970/compare-two-listt-objects-for-equality-ignoring-order

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if all elements in `combo` are also in `playerCombo`, or that you want to check if *one* element in `combo` is also in `playerCombo`, or something else, entirely??

Comment: This is a really basic C# Question and has nothing to do with Unity3D. Also its already multiply times answered on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669970/compare-two-listt-objects-for-equality-ignoring-order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition needs to be something like this:

```
public bool IsListSame(List<int> combo, List<int> playerCombo) {

    if (combo.Count != playerCombo.Count)
        return false;

    for (int n = 0; n < combo.Count; n++) {
        bool found = false;
        for (int m = 0; m < playerCombo.Count; m++) {
             if (combo[n] == playerCombo[m]) {
                 found = true;
                 break;
             }
        }
        if (!found) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This implementation disregards the order of the items in the list, that is correct.  You could easily modify this code to ensure all items in the list are in the same order.

Comment: why break after return

Comment: Because I wrote it on the fly and made a mistake.  Thanks I fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

LINQ provides the extension method [Enumerable.SequenceEqual()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) that can be used as follows:

```
using System.Linq;
// ...

found = combo.SequenceEqual(playerCombo);
```

This method will return true if the two lists are the same length and the corresponding elements are equal according to their default equality comparer.